# In ZFC is possible to define Kuratowski's ordered pair using only the axiom of empty set and the axiom of union?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Kuratowski's pair is defined as $$ (a,b)=\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}. $$

I ask about the existence of this set without the assumption of the axiom of pair.

Comment: With only assumption of axiom of empty set and axiom of union, you can't prove existence of any set but empty set.

Comment: @Wojowu Well, we are additionally given $a$ and $b$ as "input parametes". Nevertheless, in the specific case $a=b=\emptyset$, we have no way to obtain $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$ as would be needed.

Comment: How would you prove the existence of $\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$ *without* the statement that says "$\{a,b\}$ exists" ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to prove this from just the empty set axiom and the union axiom.  Indeed, note that if $M=\{\emptyset\}$ then $(M,\in)$ satisfies the empty set axiom and the union axiom (since $\bigcup \emptyset=\emptyset$).  But taking $a=b=\emptyset$, $M$ does not contain $(\emptyset,\emptyset)$.

(Actually, depending on how you phrase "the Kuratowski ordered pair exists", it might be true that $M\vDash(\emptyset,\emptyset)\text{ exists}$.  In particular, you might write "$(a,b)$ exists" as "there exists $P$ such that for all $x$, $x\in P$ iff either for all $y$, $y\in x$ iff $y=a$ or for all $y$, $y\in x$ iff $y=a$ or $y=b$".  With this definition, there does not exist any $x$ satisfying the final part of the definition, so $\emptyset$ actually satisfies the definition of $(\emptyset,\emptyset)$ in $M$.  To fix this, you can instead take $M=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$.  Then $M$ still satisfies the union axiom, and any element of $M$ that satisfied the definition of $(\emptyset,\emptyset)$ would have to have $\{\emptyset\}$ as an element.)